# Got downvote reputation cost back 4 times when post was removed

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, downvotes, deleted-answers

Last night I downvoted and flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39099036/jquery-validator-date-not-binding-to-nullable-datetime-in-asp-net-core/39759292#39759292). A bit later the post was removed, my rep counter said '+3' and I see this in my history:

> +1    5 hours ago     removed     jQuery validator date not binding to nullable DateTime in Asp.net Core
>   +1    5 hours ago     removed     jQuery validator date not binding to nullable DateTime in Asp.net Core
>   +1    5 hours ago     removed     jQuery validator date not binding to nullable DateTime in Asp.net Core
>   +1    5 hours ago     removed     jQuery validator date not binding to nullable DateTime in Asp.net Core
>   -1    7 hours ago     downvoted   jQuery validator date not binding to nullable DateTime in Asp.net Core

They all link to that same post. It seems I got the rep back 4 times instead of just once.

On /reputation I see this:

```
-- 2016-09-26 rep 0     = 11369     
 2  38828248 (5)
-- 2016-09-27 rep +5    = 11374     
 2  20203135 (10)
-- 2016-09-28 rep +10   = 11384     
-- 2016-09-29 rep 0     = 11384
```

Comment: Somebody up there likes you :)

Comment: Yesterday, I got my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39746517/revisions) approved twice and got `+4` ... is that related or should I open a new question?

Comment: @Sundeep no. You have 2 separate suggested edits on that post. The +4 is by design

Comment: I realize accounting for an extra +3 is tough when you have 11k but do you know if you got the rep back 4 times or did it just show up in your history 4 times?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I really have no idea unfortunately. It may be that it only shows up 4 times, I'll edit the question to include the last part of the /reputation log. Not sure if it contains all information needed to determine that.

Comment: @psubsee2003 as far as I remember I submitted only once.. if I click the `edit approved` links, both take me to same page.. both were approved by same reviewer and OP, probably in quick succession.. in between my edit was improved by the reviewer but now reviewer's edit is missing..

Comment: A bit OT I realise, but may I ask why you downvoted it in the first place?

Comment: @IanWorthington Because it wasn't an answer, it was a "me too" comment. After such posts enter the review queue, they usually receive a (pre-set) comment like this: *"This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. You can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation."*

Comment: Ah, you flagged an answer not the original question?  I see someone has DVed the question for reasons that aren't clear to me: my SO bete noire.

Comment: @IanWorthington in any case, downvotes on questions cost nothing, so it wouldn't apply either way.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

We had some fun with scheduled tasks last night. Your reputation is queued for a recalc when a post that's affected your reputation is deleted... Somehow, that recalc got run four times, simultaneously.

They all calculated the correct reputation for you... But they also each recorded a deletion entry for that answer. So your rep history notes the +1 four times instead of 1.

This'll all be fixed next time your reputation recalculates. Concurrency, wooo!

Comment: This sort of answer is why I hang out on Meta.

Comment: Just out of behind the scenes curiosity, what happened from a technical standpoint to have the script execute in 4 places at the same time?

Comment: No idea, @Travis. Bunch of crap was going haywire, this included. Possibly related to the DNS issues SRE is fighting with right now; had a bunch of failover servers not... waiting for stuff to fail. Or, maybe Stijn is just really lucky! He should at least drop a quarter in the nearest slot machine today, just in case.

Comment: Or buy a lotto ticket.

Comment: Mainly I want to know how I can get in on the spurious +3 rep goodness ;)  This, incidentally, reminds me of a great piece of wisdom: https://twitter.com/mattpodwysocki/status/393474697699921921